# How to copy out multiple columns from multiple Excel workbooks to a single consolidated workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd, xlwt

I have the following task which I was hoping to get some help on.
I'm using Python, and can't decide which of xlrd & xlwt or Pandas would be more useful. (OR if by the end anyone has a suggestion for a better programming language please go ahead)

I've got a whole bunch of Excel workbooks all sitting in different directories. I was wanting to look through all of the different worksheets in these .xlsx files for specific headers like "name", "team", and "number of xyz", and copy the entire columns with these headers to a new "Output.xlsx" workbook, with different sheets.
(The columns of interest may be dispersed between other columns of irrelevant information and formatting in the different spreadsheets may not always be uniform)

The issue is that the same names and team info of individuals appear over and over again in these spreadsheets, but the data I'm looking for (like number of tackles in a game) changes over time, as the spreadsheets have been made.

**Example**

game_1_stats.xlsx

```
 Player             Team    Handballs    Tackles   Marks    Kicks
 Luke Hodge         Hawthorn    20        8         10        5
 Andrew Mcleod      Crows      10         5          8        18
```

game_2_stats.xlsx

```
 Player             Team    Tackles   Fouls against Fouls for   Kicks
 Luke Hodge         Hawthorn    8         8         4           20
 Andrew Mcleod      Crows      5          1          1        11
```

game_3_stats.xlsx

```
 Player             Team         Kicks   Goals Behinds Marks Tackles
 Andrew Mcleod      Crows          16      7      4     8      3
 Shane Woewodin     Collingwood    0       0      0     0      0
 Luke Hodge         Hawthorn       25      2      1     9      5
```

game_4_stats.xlsx

```
 Player             Team    Handballs    Tackles   Marks    Kicks
 Luke Hodge         Hawthorn    20        8         10        5
 Andrew Mcleod      Crows      10         5          8        18
```

So if each of these "game_x_stats.xlsx" files were stored in a different directory for 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, etc, and I was only interested in the **Tackles** and **Kicks** data, I was hoping to create the following with Python

consolidated_historical_player_statistics.xlsx

```
 Year                             2012          2013         2014        2015
 Player             Team    Tackles Kicks Tackles Kicks  Tackles Kicks   Tackles Kicks
 Luke Hodge         Hawthorn    5   20         0   8       10    30         3    15
 Andrew Mcleod      Crows       .........................(same as above)..........
```

I wasn't sure if Pandas or xlrd would be more suitable to do this. I don't need to run any real maths formulas or analysis of this data, just to copy a whole bunch of columns of a changing data field (like tackles and kicks), that correspond to a particular player. (And do this for multiple players - obviously more than 2)

I have the following bit of code that looks through all of the .xlsx folders in file path "Player Statistics", and for each iteration of an individual spreasheet that's found, it prints out the list of Players with the "name" header.

But what I want to do is look for multiple column headers, and instead of printing it out, I want to write to a new spreadsheet.

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

path_with_multiple_directories_and_documents = "C:/Software"
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('Consolidated player statistics')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_with_multiple_directories_and_documents):
     xlsfiles = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('xlsx')]
     for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
         workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
         for worksheet in workbook.sheets():
             for row in range(worksheet.nrows):
                 if worksheet.row_values(row)[0] == 'name':
                     print("This should be a printed list of the Player Names found in this document \n")
                     cv = worksheet.col_values(row)
                     print(cv,"\n")
```

I hope this wasn't too generic, but I feel like this would be a pretty handy piece of code to have, to automate the process of having to copy and paste heaps of different columns from all over the place
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: if you know `vba` at all, it could very easily get you the information you need as well as. it's very possible to search column headers for specific words and then do a lookup on names and copy the values to a a spreadsheet.

Comment: ... and DO NOT merge the cells containing the years across multiple columns. All you will be doing is making everything you do in the future harder.

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman , is vba an "easier" way of doing this? I'm not familiar with vba which is why I was hoping to do it in Python. But I will also be getting familiar with vba to see if i can do it that way